django reverting change of user info
I want to change the user email (and other informations about the user)
So I created a route for it, it's a minimal example that should work for changing email:
@login_required
def change_email(request):
    email = request.POST['email']

    if email != request.user.email:
        request.user.email = email

    request.user.save()
    return JsonResponse({ 'message': 'Email updated' })

The email is changed, but after one or two requests, the email is back to the old one.
Giving more context, I have two django apps: pong and api. pong is responsible for SSR templates and returning the pages to the front:
# Custom render func I use to render templates in SPA
def render(request, template_name, context={}, status=200):
    if request.headers.get('X-Transcendence'):
        return django_render(request, template_name, context, status=status)

    template_html = loader.get_template(template_name).render(context, request)
    return django_render(request, 'base.html', { 'content': template_html }, status=status)

<!-- change_email.html -->
<span id="message"></span>
<span id="error"></span>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'api:change_email' %}" onsubmit="handleChangeEmail(event)">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{ request.user.email }}" required>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

// handler func
async function handleChangeEmail(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const response = await fetchData(event.target.action, {
    method: event.target.method,
    body: new FormData(event.target),
  });

  const data = await response.json();

  document.getElementById("message").innerText = data.message || "";
  document.getElementById("error").innerText = data.error || ""
}


I could not find a solution to this. I created a minimal app to reproduce it and it works fine. In this app, I'm using channels, twilio, and have some configuration, I dont know if any of it could be interfering in requests or database.

There are a few issues with your code: 
A) The function always returns "Email updated". 
B) There is no handle for the case that request.user.save() is erroneous.
Change it like this:
@login_required
def change_email(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return JsonResponse({ 'message': 'No get request allowed' })

    email = request.POST['email']

    if email == request.user.email:
        return JsonResponse({ 'message': 'Email already saved' })        

    request.user.email = email
    try:
        request.user.save()
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)
    
    return JsonResponse({ 'message': 'Email updated' })

This should help to give more info about what happens. The code is still far away from perfect: It lacks email validation, csrf protection and handling the case of a GET request. You should also add appropriate error codes, e.g. JsonResponse({'message': 'Email updated'}, status=200)

'error': str(e) do you really need to return the string representation of the exception that occurred? Do you really think the frontend / user needs to know that? Just return some generic error to them instead, no need for users to be aware of whatever exception occurred there (unless you specifically handle those, like duplicate emails, etc.)

You are right. As I've written above: "This should help to give more info about what happens. The code is still far away from perfect". I did not attempt to give perfect code, I attempted to shed light on what happens.

I added more information about the frontend. I tested this to see if there are any erros while saving, but there are none. The email gets saved, but after refreshing the page a few times it goes back to the old one. I only have this route for changing it, so I added a print there to see when its called, and when it changes back there is no api call there.

Could the reason be that your html defines to poll the email from the request like value="{{ request.user.email }}"? Wouldn't it be better to let the user write it himself? Most importantly you have to turn off the logic for GET requests as said in my answer. If there is still unexpected behavior I think the error lays elsewhere...

Yes, it was elsewhere, I was just going to sleep and turned on the pc cause I thought about that, LOL
Thank you for the help, the problem could be anywhere so I wasnt able to provide very much about the whole app.

I found the solution.
The AsyncWebsocketConsumer dont update the self.scope['user'] correctly when a change is made to the user.
In my case, I was using the websocket for sending online/offline status in real time to other users.
After updating email and refreshing the page, the user disconnect was setting user.status = 'Offline' and saving, the problem is that this user from the websocket was the old user, before the changes, and this save overwrites everything.

This websocket updating the user wasn't mentioned in your question making it lack debugging details. Please edit your question so it has a proper [mre].
